# Почему в Android Studio в Tools отсутствует меню Android и SDK?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, reactjs, mobile-development, react-native

Подготавливаю окружение для разработки на React Native под Windows. Во всех статьях ( ну например тут https://jsmantras.com/blog/Installing-React-Native... ) и мануалах после всех подготовительных действий в IDE Android Studion в меню Tools есть пункт Android со вложенными пунктами взаимодействия с SDK, AVD и т.п. Но у меня почему-то такой пункт отсутствует. Не пойму почему... Ниже приведу составляющие окружения.

**Java SDK - установлен**
[image]

**Android SDK - установлена**
[image]

**Системная переменная ANDROID_HOME - создана**
[image]

**Настройки SDK в Android Studio - вроде правильные**
[image]

**Ожидаемый результат - необходимые пункты меню**
[image]

**По факту - пунктов нет**
[image]

Подскажите, чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема решилась? Подскажите как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо запустить Resourse Manager и добавить Android module

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том что Вы открыли проект как внешнюю директорию, а нужно открыть его как проект. Иначе говоря корнем вашего проекта должна быть папка **android**